DIY USB-C cable not recognised by USB PD power source
I'm trying to replace a wire from my camera's dummy battery from it's PCB -> barrel jack -> USB A cable to just female USB C.
I've got ready made USB-C female to 4 bare conductors cable.
I've Soldered Vbus and GND pins to + and - poles on dummy battery PCB and this setup will happily run when powered from very old 5V USB A charger via USB A to C cable, however my newer USB PD charger won't recognize it. Neither my USB C power bank will, with its built-in USB C cable.
Original dummy battery would work via its original USB A -> Barrel Jack -> Dummy battery cable on the new PD power bank.
I've destructively disassembled both the USB A to barrel jack cable and dummy battery itself but I can't see anything that would differ original setup from mine. No circuitry, data pins in the plug not connected to anything, no sign of any other components.
How do I make my cable (which in the end the dummy battery becomes, just + and - on the bare pcb, no other components) be recognized by PD chargers and power banks? I don't need it to supply anything more than 5V 1A.

You need 5.1 kohm resistors on the CC pins to signal that there is a device connected which requires 5V supply.

Huh, so if usb-c breakout board only has G, D1, D2 and V there is no way to make it work?

@gmp Nope. But the breakout board may contain a place for adding a resistor. But you need to know if the resistor is a pull-up (for supply side) or a pull-down (for device side), so you might still have a wrong breakout board. We don't know what you bought. Which exact breakout board you have?

I desleeved cables I ordered for this project and these have JRC-B008 board inside. Which according to this thread has CC pads exposed on the back side. Guess I can reuse them after adding the resistor. Thanks for the help!
